# How to implement something similar to Fancy indexing in Julia?

Tags: indexing, julia

I am very to new to Julia. Therefore, please excuse me if this is a silly problem.

I have a 4*4 Matrix `AA`.

```
julia> AA
4×4 Array{Int64,2}:
  1   2   3   4
  5   6   7   8
  9  10  11  12
 13  14  15  16
```

I have an array `pv` and `pq` containing indexing information.

```
julia> pv
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 3
 4

julia> pq
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 2
 1
 4
```

I wish to assign zero to the elements `AA[1,2]`, `AA[3,1]` and `AA[4,4]`.

If I run `AA[pv,pq] = 0` then output is:

```
4×4 Array{Int64,2}:
 0  0   3  0
 5  6   7  8
 0  0  11  0
 0  0  15  0
```

But I need this as output

```
4×4 Array{Int64,2}:
  1   0   3   4
  5   6   7   8
  0  10  11  12
 13  14  15  0
```

I know this is called Fancy Indexing in Python. But, how can I do this in Julia? I cannot run two if-statements with variables which checking row and column index.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding my 2¢ for completion,

Julia supports 'column-major-order' linear indices like matlab (although I note that Julia 1.0 has deprecated the `sub2ind` and `ind2sub` matlab-equivalent functions).

Therefore, if you could express (or already had) your coordinates in "linear indices" form, you could use those directly for your indexing.

In practice, in the current state of julia, this does not look much different to using a Cartesian Index, but it may be preferred in some cases, e.g. if you know you will be reusing those indices for further operations, or for readability / shifting from matlab code etc.

E.g.

```
julia> A = copy( reshape( 10:10:160, (4,4) )' )
4×4 Array{Int64,2}:
  10   20   30   40
  50   60   70   80
  90  100  110  120
 130  140  150  160

julia> pv = [1,3,4];   pq = [2,1,4];

julia> A_linearIndices = LinearIndices(A)
4×4 LinearIndices{2,Tuple{Base.OneTo{Int64},Base.OneTo{Int64}}}:
 1  5   9  13
 2  6  10  14
 3  7  11  15
 4  8  12  16

julia> L = [ A_linearIndices[i...] for i in zip(pv, pq) ]
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
  5
  3
 16

julia> A[L]
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
  20
  90
 160

julia> A[L] .= 0; A
4×4 Array{Int64,2}:
  10    0   30   40
  50   60   70   80
   0  100  110  120
 130  140  150    0
```

Having said that, if you wanted to keep something for later indexing, you could also be saving a Boolean matrix for logical indexing via the same approach.

---

<sub>**EDIT**: Code edited to show assignment via linear index too. Note that I had to make A a proper array, rather than keep as a "ReshapedArray" object, as the latter complains if you try to index it directly.</sub>

Comment: That is indeed another way to tackle the problem. This way I can use the indexing further also. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Well, obviously you can save and use the resulting CartesianIndex object from DSM's answer further too. I don't think my answer is more canonical than his / hers, feel free to choose that as the answer. I was just writing this for completion, but personally I would suggest DSM's answer as the most canonical and straightforward answer to your question (in the context of Julia 1.0, at least -- this might change in the future).

Answer (score 7):

Another option would be to use CartesianIndex:

```
julia> AA[CartesianIndex.(pv, pq)]
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
  2
  9
 16

julia> AA[CartesianIndex.(pv, pq)] .= 0
3-element view(::Array{Int64,2}, CartesianIndex{2}[CartesianIndex(1, 2), CartesianIndex(3, 1), CartesianIndex(4, 4)]) with eltype Int64:
 0
 0
 0

julia> AA
4×4 Array{Int64,2}:
  1   0   3   4
  5   6   7   8
  0  10  11  12
 13  14  15   0
```

Note that you have to use `.=` instead of `=` or you'll get a mysterious `no method matching setindex_shape_check(::Int64, ::Int64)` error in 1.0.. which gives a nice deprecation warning in 0.7 which is what I should probably still be using. ;-)

Comment: Was going to send `CartesianIndex` solution, just seen yours. Why do you `zip`? I do not think it is needed. `AA[CartesianIndex.(pv,pq)] .= 0` seems to work fine.

Comment: Nice solution. I tried it as well but didn't think of broadcasting.

Answer (score 4):

One option is

```
julia> for el in zip(pv, pq)
           AA[el...] = 0
       end

julia> AA
4×4 Array{Int64,2}:
  1   0   3   4
  5   6   7   8
  0  10  11  12
 13  14  15   0
```

Comment: Or simply a double loop: `for j in pq, i in pv; A[i, j] = 0; end`

Comment: @fredrikekre No, that's two nested loops again, resulting in all the combinations -- exactly what the OP wants to avoid.

Comment: Exactly, nested loops dont work. Also, if I use A[pv,pq]=0, this is also equivalent to nested loops.

Comment: This solution is actually a _lot_ faster than the `CartesianIndex` solution (~10x), partly because you avoid allocating an index array. Unfortunately, I cannot find a way to fuse the broadcasted version. E.g. `setindex!.(Ref(A), CartesianIndex.(pv, pq)) .= 0` fails.